# How to keep values after form submit

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to keep the value of the selected option in a drop down after a submit in a form. I have tried different things but none is working. I tried this:

```
    <select name="foo">
  <option value="<?php echo $_POST['foo'] ?? ''; ?>" 
    <?php if((isset($_POST['foo']) && $_POST['foo'] == 'bar') || ($_SESSION["bike"] == 'Bike 1'))
          echo ' selected="selected"';?> > Bike 1</option>
  <option value="<?php echo $_POST['foo'] ?? ''; ?>" 
    <?php if((isset($_POST['foo']) && $_POST['foo'] == 'bar') || ($_SESSION["bike"] == 'Bike 2')) 
          echo ' selected="selected"';?> > Bike 2</option>
     </select>
```

This drop down is placed in a form with a submit button. When pressing the submit with Bike 2 selected it will clear all variables and select Bike 1. How can I keep the Selected bike 2 after the submit?

Comment: You missed to `endif;`

Comment: Try to use variables instead of using `if` in HTML. Or use a template system.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="foo">
    <option value="<?php echo $_POST['foo'] ?? ''; ?>" <?php if( (isset($_POST['foo']) && $_POST['foo'] == 'bar') || (!empty($_SESSION['bike'] && $_SESSION["bike"] == 'Bike 1') ) { echo ' selected="selected"'; }?> > Bike 1</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $_POST['foo'] ?? ''; ?>" <?php if( (isset($_POST['foo']) && $_POST['foo'] == 'bar') || (!empty($_SESSION['bike'] && $_SESSION["bike"] == 'Bike 2') ) { echo ' selected="selected"'; }?> > Bike 2</option>
</select>
```